# VSCode EJS extension, disables the HTML auto complete

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, ejs, emmet

So, I recently started working with [EJS](http://ejs.co/) files within VSCode. Anyway, when I added the EJS extension, I lost all of HTML emmet functionality in my EJS files. However without the EJS extension HTML works fine but I obviously lose the JS syntax highlighting. Is there any work around for this?

What is the best set-up for working with EJS files in VSCode?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

*Guess you already made it work, but I'm gonna leave this here for future reference.*

Add this to your Settings:

```
{
  ...,
  ...,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "ejs": "html"
  }
}
```

[The VS-Code docs tell us how to configure emmet for any file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration)

Comment: how would i add html and javascript to ejs?

Comment: should be just 
`"ejs": ["html", "javascript"]`
OR
`"ejs": "html",
"ejs": "javascript"
`
That's my assumption anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings.json file ... within the .vscode folder in the root of your project put this:

```
{
    // ... your other settings if you have them ...

    "files.associations": {
        // This will enable html vscode autocompletion in EJS files
        "*.ejs": "html"
    }
}
```

It will make your ejs files to autocomplete with html tags from vscode.

General advice for Web Development is that it is better to have ClientSite-JS in different JS files and ServerSide-JS in Express js files/routers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pret [.prettierignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html)

Create .prettierignore file and add certain file extension what you want to ignore.

```
# all ejs files
*.ejs
```